kubernetes nodes created by status is not ready
Docker Desktop For Windows on WSL2
I'm following the k8s blog here :
https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/05/21/wsl-docker-kubernetes-on-the-windows-desktop/
and seeing the nodes created but perpetually with Status = NotReady.
x@y:~$ cat << EOF > kind-3nodes.yaml
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
  - role: control-plane
  - role: worker
  - role: worker
EOF
x@y:~$ kind create cluster --name wslkindmultinodes --config ./kind-3nodes.yaml
Creating cluster "wslkindmultinodes" ...
 ✓ Ensuring node image (kindest/node:v1.17.0) 
 ✓ Preparing nodes   
 ✓ Writing configuration 
 ✓ Starting control-plane ️
 ✓ Installing CNI 
 ✓ Installing StorageClass 
 ✓ Joining worker nodes 
Set kubectl context to "kind-wslkindmultinodes"
You can now use your cluster with:

kubectl cluster-info --context kind-wslkindmultinodes

Thanks for using kind! 
x@y:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                              STATUS     ROLES    AGE   VERSION
wslkindmultinodes-control-plane   NotReady   master   62s   v1.17.0
wslkindmultinodes-worker          NotReady   <none>   28s   v1.17.0
wslkindmultinodes-worker2         NotReady   <none>   28s   v1.17.0
x@y:~$

It appears that CNI is not initialized :
  Ready            False   Sat, 14 Dec 2024 21:21:43 -0800   Sat, 14 Dec 2024 20:33:42 -0800   KubeletNotReady
    runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized

Apparently route to Docker is linkdown :
johng@X17R1:~$ ip route show
default via 172.25.112.1 dev eth0 proto kernel
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.25.112.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.25.119.83


Try to install a more recent version of kind,
curl -Lo ./kind https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/dl/v0.20.0/kind-linux-amd64
chmod +x ./kind
sudo mv ./kind /usr/local/bin/kind


Wow that worked. Could you explain more how I got an older version of kind and why it would fail to properly configure networking ?

kind is the only element on that page which is out of date.

Now I'm able to create kubernetes dashboard and run a proxy but creating a token fails :
x@y:/mnt/c/Users/johng$ kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard describe secret $(kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get secret | grep admin-user | awk '{print $1}')
Returns empty Data sections.

Nodes once again are in NotReady status. A number of times I've started from scratch. I've carefully followed all the instructions on the page. ( The very first time, I'm not sure how kind was not installed to latest version, but now I'm ensuring it's at latest. ) But still for a freshly created cluster the nodes are in NotReady status.

runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized

Please consider raising another question by giving all the details about what you've done since last time the problem was fixed.
